# Why does Powershell interpret log2 45/120 as log2 "45/120"?

Tags: powershell, syntax

Given a function: 

`function log2 {param ([double]$x) [Math]::Log($x) / [Math]::Log(2) }`

Expected: `log2 45/120` should yield `-1.41503749928`

Actual:

`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'x'. Cannot convert value "45/120" to type "System.Double". 
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format." 
At line:1 char:6 
+ log2 45/120 
+ ~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [log2], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,log2`
 
Why is that?

[Uservoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/32679136-log2-45-120-should-be-valid-syntax)

Comment: Not a bug, [this is by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't know if `45/100` as an argument to a command is supposed to be an evaluated expression or a string, so it chooses a string.  It does that to preserve the argument for the command.  It tries to cast the string to a double, and it can't because it's not a numeric string.

For example, I enter this command:

```
Get-Value 12/19/2017
```

What should Powershell do with `12/19/2017` before it passes it to `Get-Value`?  The safest answer is *nothing*.  If `Get-Value` wants to try to convert it, that's not the command line parser's job.

Yes, these are explicit:

```
Get-Value (12/19/2017)
Get-Value "12/19/2017"
```

But Powershell needs to have a sensible default that covers everything, and they've chosen to treat all literal argument tokens as a string unless they're designated as an expression with parentheses, a subexpression with `$()`, or in some cases a script block with `{}`.

Here's another example.  Let's say I want all files with an extension of `.000` that start with `4` and end with `1`:

```
Get-ChildItem 4*1.000
```